# Is there a way in Snowflakes to get the list of tables used from given set of views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a SQL script or some metadata table for views which have the source info.

Comment: Have you tried [GET_DDL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html)?

Comment: Get DDL gets the entire view definition or table create statement, not only the source of the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES to return the list of objects referenced by a view.

Please review the below documentation for more information and example:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html#get-object-references